# What is the maximum memory limits per application for Android 2.2?

Tags: android, limits

What is the maximum memory limits per application for Android 2.2?

Comment: It depends from device to device, you can use this to get exact figure for devices: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getLargeMemoryClass()

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It depends on the particular device, usually ranges between 16 and 48 MB.

Comment: @Saddam Abu Ghaida: Then you might consider to accept and upvote his answer, since it is this system that does StackOverflow. :)

Answer (score 16):

The lower limit for a low density / small screen, and medium density / normal screen device is 16 MB.  The lower limit for a high density / normal screen device is 24 MB.  Individual device manufactures can and do raise this limit for their device, depending on how much RAM the device has (and how many megapixels the camera is etc), but if you stay within those lower limits you should be good on all devices.

Comment: Do you have a link to a definitive source for this info?  Thanks. As they say on Wikipedia citation needed.

Comment: @hackbod : I am confused after viewing this thread where the selected answer says there is no limit on internal memory per app: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8815974/external-vs-internal-memory-storage-what-shall-i-use   ; Can you please comment ?

Comment: @WinOrWin obviously the thread you are referring to is talking about "storage space"(although colloquially people might refer to it as "internal/external memory") while this thread talks about "memory", RAM. They are not the same thing. (eg. The basic difference between harddrive space and memory).

Answer (score 1):

Just a footnote(I don't currently have the enough reputation to add comment). @WinOrWin obviously the thread you are referring to is talking about "storage space"(although colloquially people might refer to it as "internal/external memory") while this thread talks about "memory", RAM. They are not the same thing. (eg. The basic difference between harddrive space and memory).