# Android: OutOfMemory while calling BitmapFactory.decodeStream()

Tags: java, android, memory, bitmap

I'm developing an Android app that has to display some pictures (usually taken by the phone's camera) on the screen. The way that I've created a bitmap is:

```
Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, "" + mediaId);
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri));
```

The 2nd line of this ends up on some handsets with OutOfMemoryException. Am I doing something wrong or maybe is there any alternative way of doing the same?

Thanks in advance for any ideas

Answer (score 0):

The photos from the camera are several MBs large. Android applications have a maximum of 24MB RAM available (see [What is the maximum memory limits per application for Android 2.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590443/what-is-the-maximum-memory-limits-per-application-for-android-2-2))

So if your application has several images from the camera, it won't fit in the RAM available to your application.

Scaling down your image(s) is the only solution I am afraid...

Comment: thank you! I've tried scaling down, at some point it helps but still I've seen apps which display pictures in a full screen mode somehow :(

Comment: If those applications only show one picture at the time, they might destroy the image data to clear memory... (or also scale down images, as the screen is a *lot* smaller than the images taken by the camera)