# Android Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) from asyncTask

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, ui-thread

I have a working android game which occasionally force closes on slow devices with the error

> Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 14620 (AsyncTask #1)

Research indicated to me that this was due to delaying the execution of the UI thread, so, i bundled up the peace of code (about 200 lines of bitmap and region creation) into an AsyncTask (doInBackground method) and i now run that task from the UI thread using task.execute.

The problem is, this has in no way stopped the error. If anything the app force closes more frequently during the execution of that code despite the fact it should be running in an asyncTask.

In the interest of being thorough, the error is triggered during the execution of this part of the code (extract from the 200ish block):

```
Back.outerPath.setFillType(Path.FillType.EVEN_ODD);

    Region tempRegion = new Region(PathBoundsRectangle);

    Back.outerRegion.setPath(Back.outerPath, tempRegion);
    Back.innerRegion.setPath(Back.innerPath, tempRegion);
    Back.fastRegion.setPath(Back.speedPath, tempRegion);
    Back.slowRegion.setPath(Back.slowPath, tempRegion);

    Back.outerRegion.op(Back.innerRegion, Region.Op.XOR);

    Matrix scaleMatrix = new Matrix();
    RectF rectF = new RectF();
    Back.innerPath.computeBounds(rectF, true);
    scaleMatrix.setScale(1.1f, 1.1f,rectF.centerX(),rectF.centerY());
    Back.innerPath.transform(scaleMatrix);

    Back.outerPath.computeBounds(rectF, true);
    scaleMatrix.setScale(0.9f, 0.9f,rectF.centerX(),rectF.centerY());
    Back.outerPath.transform(scaleMatrix);

    Back.outerSideBandRegion.setPath(Back.outerPath, tempRegion);
    Back.outerSideBandRegion.op(Back.outerRegion, Region.Op.XOR);

    Back.innerSideBandRegion.setPath(Back.innerPath, tempRegion);
    Back.innerSideBandRegion.op(Back.innerRegion, Region.Op.XOR);
```

Any ideas? Is it possible the code is still running on the UI thread? Can this error be due to something else?

EDIT: It turns out the error is coming from the Region.op.XOR manipulations. Anyone see how this could cause a Fatal Error?

Comment: Your not doing a .get() are you?

Comment: No, not doing a .get().

Comment: You may be hitting a memory limit on older devices, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590443/what-is-the-maximum-memory-limits-per-application-for-android-2-2

Comment: Petro, the app force closes with same error despite that modification.

Comment: Ok, did you look into the memory consumption of the app? Bitmaps are usually fairly large, I ran into an issue on an app once where we had to convert images to a more compact format to work properly.

Comment: Must be because of memory, thanks, but i don't know how to reduce memory consumption.

Comment: You could try shrinking the sizes of the "region" your rendering, that would reduce the overall memory footprint.

Comment: No problem, let me know if that helps and I will formulate a short answer so that future readers can be made aware. Good luck!

Comment: Ok, so it's not a memory error, reduced memory usage drastically and same error. Just kill me.

Comment: Post a complete stack trace of a crash.  Post the invocation of the AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

I have also observed this when calling `Region.Op.INTERSECT` on regions derived from extremely long and complex paths.

The solution that works for me is to maintain a record of all the path waypoints, and then to build a list of smaller paths onto which the `Region.Op.INTERSECT` operation gets executed individually.